# create root level gradle task to be used by several subprojects?

Tags: groovy, gradle, tar

I want to create a task in my root project that will create a custom TAR for some subprojects.

```
task archive(type: Tar) {
    project.logger.info("Tar bundle :: ")
    baseName = project.baseName
    destinationDir = new File(project.buildDir.path)
    archiveDir = new File(project.buildDir.path)
    compression = Compression.GZIP
    from (archiveDir)
}
```

I have found this task but what I need, is a subproject to send in the subproject.name and have the task use the buildDir and the source dir from the subproject calling the task. Then save the archive to /target of the subproject as well.

Is this possible without creating a new task for each subproject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If every subproject is supposed to create its own Tar, then you need to create one task per subproject. This is as easy as wrapping the task declaration in `subprojects { ... }`. You'll also have to remove all occurrences of `project.` from your code, plus the whole `baseName` line. (All of this is redundant anyway.)

`new File(project.buildDir.path)` is the same as `buildDir`. Instead of `logger.info("Tar bundle :: ")`, you probably want `doFirst { logger.info("Tar bundle :: ") }`. Otherwise, this message will get logged for each and every build, no matter which tasks get executed.